# Cannot load jPlayer

Tags: jquery, jplayer

I am trying to load jPlayer in my application. Here's my code:

```
$('#jQuery_jPlayer1').jPlayer({
    ready: function () {
    $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
      m4v: "/Users/itsme/Desktop/sample_video.m4v"
    });
    },
    supplied: "m4v"
});
```

I do not see anything added on the screen within div#jQuery_jPlayer1.

However, this is added to the HTML of div#jQuery_jPlayer1.

Can anyone help me with what I'm doing wrong? Why the video player is not loaded?

Thanks.

Comment: on which browser you are checking ??

Comment: Can you include exactly how you are defining the div element that you're filling?

Comment: <div id="jQuery_jPlayer1"></div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, it's cause it cannot access the file on my desktop, if i have a file within my server directory, it works. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function(){
     $('#jQuery_jPlayer1').jPlayer({
    ready: function () {
    $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
      m4v: "/Users/itsme/Desktop/sample_video.m4v"
    });
    },
    supplied: "m4v"
});
    });
```

Comment: i have my code within jQuery(document).ready(function(){...}, of course.